# to watch me play - what rules are here

Tags: syntax

Here is an [excerpt from The Art of Learning](https://books.google.co.uk/books?id=XUwOtdcIWdkC&pg=PA69&lpg=PA69&dq=%22More%20and%20more%20fans%20came%20to%20my%20tournaments%20to%20watch%20me%20play%20and%20get%20autographs%22&source=bl&ots=I4bVGd-eR8&sig=ACfU3U2nlQWU5X5cW6cQGzQegrIGTg38tA&hl=en&sa=X&ved=2ahUKEwibh9WggObhAhWVo3EKHf-wA54Q6AEwAHoECAEQAQ#v=onepage&q=%22More%20and%20more%20fans%20came%20to%20my%20tournaments%20to%20watch%20me%20play%20and%20get%20autographs%22&f=false):

> More and more fans came to my tournaments to watch **me play** and get autographs.

My questions is should not it be:

1. either *More and more fans came to my tournaments to watch **my games** and get autographs*
2. or *More and more fans came to my tournaments to watch **me playing** and get autographs*
3. or, in order to avoid fused gerund, *More and more fans came to my tournaments to watch **my playing** and get autographs*, but to be honest this option sound weird to me and it is better to use the first option.

If *me play* is fine, then what are the rules, can you delineate a syntax tree for the sentence?

P.S. I am primarily interested in BrE, if it matters here.

Answer (score 1):

As a native English speaker, the sentence sounds fine to me.

If it helps, I see the the base sentence as "They came to watch me". Almost any verb can be added after "me". They came to watch me sing, or watch me dance.

Comment: Yes, looks like google ngram corroborates it as well - https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=watch+me+playing%2Cwatch+me+play&year_start=1800&year_end=2000&corpus=15&smoothing=3&share=&direct_url=t1%3B%2Cwatch%20me%20playing%3B%2Cc0%3B.t1%3B%2Cwatch%20me%20play%3B%2Cc0#t1%3B%2Cwatch%20me%20playing%3B%2Cc0%3B.t1%3B%2Cwatch%20me%20play%3B%2Cc0